# Do original languages in Greek and Hebrew Bible texts use formal or informal language where traditional translations in English used Thee and Thou?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, entomology

After reading comments re: use of Thee and Thou vis-a-vis accuracy of translations to modern (not Elizabethan) English, all very informative, I am still wondering if the original texts of Hebrew and Greek Bible used a distinctly different grammar when addressing the Deity. Or conversely, was the same language used, with perhaps reverence displayed in the context?

Comment: You're asking about Greek and Hebrew usage aren't you?  Probably not the best site to ask about those.

Comment: As High Performance Mark has pointed out, questions about Hebrew and Greek don't fit well on this site.  But this part is relevant to English: perhaps I'm misreading your question, but it looks like you're suggesting that saying something like, "show me **thy** glory" implies reverence.  Just the opposite, in fact.  Using *thy/thee/thou* implies familiarity, not reverence.  The Hebrew of Exodus 33:18 does use second person singular (*thy* not *your*), but Biblical Hebrew didn't have the T-V distinction, so it's hard to say what translation would be most correct.

Comment: I'm not an expert on biblical language, so take this with a grain of salt. But the King James Bible seems to have translated singular 2nd person as *thou/thee* and plural 2nd person as *ye/you*, without taking formality into account. From 2 Samuel: "And Ziba said, I humbly beseech thee that I may find grace in thy sight, my lord, O king. "

Comment: The original Hebrew uses the singular heavily and differentiates between you and thou. And the Bible does have a poetic, lofty sound. But it's the fact that thou/thy are unused today that makes them sound formal.

Comment: Perhaps [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place. They have [questions](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek+hebrew) about translation from Greek and Hebrew.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about ancient Greek and Hebrew, not English